# Refer to column name using variable in PROC SQL

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS so please bear with me.

I have monthly data for the trailing 7 months.  It goes through a `PROC TRANSPOSE` such that the resulting table has columns named FEB2015, MAR2015,...,AUG2015.  These columns will change each month I rerun my program so that the earliest month will go from Feb to Mar, etc. in successive months of reruns.  I want to be able to reference this "earliest month" later on in the program.  For example, I'd like to run a `PROC SQL` that returns rows that have no values in the FEB2015 column but a value under 1000 in the AUG2015 Column and I'd like to do this based on the fact that the columns are named after last month, and the month 7 months ago.

Here's an example of code I'd be trying to run.  Assume the table has columns row_ID, FEB2015, MAR2015, APR2015, MAY2015, JUN2015, JUL2015, AUG2015, all integers.

```
%let first = put(intnx('month',today(),-7,'begin'), MONYY7.);  
%let second = put(intnx('month',today(),-6,'begin'), MONYY7.);   
%let last = put(intnx('month',today(),-1,'begin'), MONYY7.);

PROC SQL noprint;  
   SELECT row_id, &first, &second, &last  
   FROM mytable  
   WHERE &first is missing  
     and &second is not missing
     and &last < 1000;  
QUIT;
```

I think the values in the macro variables are just being read as strings and are not being recognized as the name of the column.  I've tried wrapping them in `NLITERAL()` but haven't had any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the macro variable values are strings. Macro variable values are ALWAYS strings. The problem is that your strings are not valid names of variables. Variable names cannot have parentheses or quotes in them.  If you want to call a function in macro code you need to nest the call inside of the %SYSFUNC() macro function.

```
%let first = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-7,begin), MONYY7.);
```